# Rebrand a modified version of an Apache licensed software

Tags: licensing

I wanted to impart a few native features (menus, tabs support etc.) to the original Draw.io project. I cloned the project and started modifying, only to find that the changes I made could not be merged to Draw.io since it deviates vastly from the original project.

Due to this I decided against submitting a pull request. I was wondering if I could rebrand the software that I built and release it under the same license as of Draw.io (Apache 2).

Is it possible to do so? If it is possible, what all things would I need to do?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read the licence carefully.  If it's the usual Apache one, it's very permissive.